# Symbian textshell mode border problem

Tags: symbian

I edited epoc.ini
added textshell in the first line.
When I run from the emulator:
NO window border is shown when I run.
It prints directly to the screen, so I can't interact with it
and the console window is isolated from the emulator window
I'm runninbg Windows 7 with Screen Resolution 1280*780

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running textshell and get all this headache , just run the normal emulator and run the eshell from it, and type the name of your console application to run it.